# Increase sql connection timeout performance impact

Tags: sql-server, azure-sql-database

I see frequent sql connection timeout issues. After increasing timeout, I don’t see that anymore. Is there any impact in the performance on increasing the timeout?

Comment: Not really you aren't adressing the real problem (that probably is the performance of the SQL queries being called) so you aren't getting any difference in performance

Comment: Could you please let me know what you mean by this - that probably is the performance of the SQL queries being called

Comment: Also, what do you mean by not addressing the problem. Is increasing the timeout not the solution?

Comment: You're connecting to the SQL server to do some query against some database and get some results. Queries could be very complex (joining lot of tables from where obtain the data, with complex conditions for the joins, ...) when tables grow and got millions of records, this could be very time consuming and seems that is why you get timeouts. Said that, the *normally correct* way to resolve timeouts is trying to optimize the queries to be faster (and thats a real different and complex question)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71823867/sql-connection-timeout-expired-the-timeout-period-elapsed-during-the-post-log

Comment: Can you please check this question and answer that. I have added the code.

Answer (score 0):

Connection timeouts are not the same as query timeouts. Increasing the connection timeout setting does not affect query performance, but the question does not mention query timeouts. The queries could all be "perfect", but the connection request could timeout due to network issues, connection provider timeouts, etc. Or it could be timing out due to SQL Server "listener" not responding in time.
If increasing the connection timeout works for you, then great! It could be you just have a slow network.
Have Fun!
Ron